# Integration by parts of curl in Woltjer’s paper

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

I am reading [*A Theorem on Force-Free Magnetic Fields (1958)*](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/44/6/489.full.pdf) by L. Woltjer. He used “integrating by parts” twice and I am confused about his results.

The first one is in the equation (7). I understand the first step because he just used the relation (6) he got earlier, 
but for the second step, if I integrate it by parts, I guess it will be like
$$\int_V A\cdot \nabla\times \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} =-\int_V \dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}\cdot(\nabla\times A)dV+\int_SA\cdot\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}dS.$$

I also found a similar question [Integration by parts of $\varphi \cdot \operatorname{curl}(u)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780332/integration-by-parts-of-varphi-cdot-operatornamecurlu), but even if I use the Divergence theorem, I got
$$\int_V \dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}\cdot(\nabla\times A)dV+\int_V\nabla\cdot\left(\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}\times A\right)dV=\int_V \dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}\cdot(\nabla\times A)dV+\int_S\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}\times AdS,$$ which still has a different sign.

Even though it does not affect the final result “zero”, I hope someone could help me do integration by parts correctly for this case.

Similar thing occurred from equation (9) to equation (10). Equation (9) is
$$
\int_{V}[2 \operatorname{curl} A \cdot \operatorname{curl} \delta A-\alpha(\delta A \cdot \operatorname{curl} A+A \cdot \operatorname{curl} \delta A] d V=0
$$
Equation (10) is $
\int_{V}[\operatorname{curl} \operatorname{curl} \boldsymbol{A}-\alpha \operatorname{curl} \boldsymbol{A}] \cdot \delta A d V=0
$, while
 my result is 
$$\int_V\text{curl curl}A\cdot\delta A-\alpha(A\cdot\text{curl}\delta A+\delta A\cdot\text{curl}A)dV=0.$$ I have no idea how to deal with the extra part.

I guess I can understand both if either one is clarified. Thank you!!!

Comment: I think the paper might have an error, or maybe he chose an inward normal