# Could you please explain how to derive the following equation

Tags: numerical-methods

since $-\Delta\mathbf{m}=\mathrm{curl}^2\mathbf{m}-\nabla\mathrm{div}\mathbf{m}$ integration by parts yields:
$$\begin{aligned}\int_\Omega-\Delta\mathbf{m}\cdot\mathbf{z}dx&=\int_\Omega\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{m}\cdot\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{z}+\operatorname{div}\mathbf{m}\operatorname{div}\mathbf{z}dx\\&-\int_\Gamma(\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{m}\times\boldsymbol{n})\cdot\mathbf{z}dS-\int_\Gamma\operatorname{div}\mathbf{m}(\mathbf{z}\cdot\boldsymbol{n})dS,\end{aligned}$$
I know the Green's theorem has been used, but I'm not sure how this $\int_{\Omega}\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{m}\cdot\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{z}$ and $\int_\Gamma(\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{m}\times n)\cdot\mathbf{z}dS$ came about.

Comment: These terms come from a variant of Green's formula applied to the $\mathrm{curl}^2\mathbf{m}$ term, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076516/integration-by-parts-of-varphi-operatornamecurlu?rq=1) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780332/integration-by-parts-of-varphi-cdot-operatornamecurlu).

Comment: $curl^2m=\nabla \times \nabla \times m$?

Comment: Yes, it is a you write. Or in the original notation $\mathrm{curl}^2\mathbf{m} = \mathrm{curl}(\mathrm{curl} (\mathbf{m}))$. The power of $2$ is meant as double application of curl.

Comment: Thank you, I understand.